# SSRS Cascading Parameters

Tags: reporting-services

1. At the run time user will select the country for which the report
   should run.
2. Next we will show all states of the selected country on parameter
   screen.
3. Next we will show all cities of selected state on parameter screen.

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure, but here's what i think:

1. Create Your Parameter
2. Set your parameter value based on others parameter value, and send it to parameter data set to retrieve its data. (maybe you can use expression to do this)

Hope it would help :)

Regards,

David Tan

Comment: "I'm not really sure" wont help others, please be sure first and then post your answer

Comment: Logically it should behave like that. However I am looking for how it will behave like that. How to pass one parameter to another parameter?

Answer (score 0):

I could achieve it.

I created first a dataset for my report with Country, State and City fields. 
After this, first parameter is country, user will select the country at run time.

After this, I have added another dataset2 to select all the states based on first parameter. I created another parameter to show multiple states. For this parameter I provided 'available values' as the second dataset viz., dataset2. This dataset2 was accepting parameter country and populating the states at the run time. I provided 'default values' as well as dataset2.

This same way I implemented the 'city' parameter. It worked.

Thank you!

Comment: You achieved it by using SSRS out of the box... i.e. look on MSDN before posting... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255197.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can achieve that.

Let say you have two dropdownlist as a parameters, A and B.

- You give A list of data from dataset
- for B, you use dataset too to retrieve the data, but when you create dataset for B add filter and set parameter A as its value.
  [Add Filter for paramater B and set A as its value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3wsY.png)

Hopefully it would help :)

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Create three different parameters as country,state and city in your dataset and add one line to the dataset query as where country = @country and state = @state and city = @city.
Now coming back to your question, If your sql has duplicate countries,state or cities it wil return duplicate values so create three different datasets for three parameters.Like **"Select Distinct country from Person.country"** and state is dependent on country so write query for state as **"Select Distinct state from Person.Country where Country = @country"** and same goes for city.

Hope this answers the question